# Power BI - Sort a Filter List of text not alphabetically

Tags: database, filter, powerbi, dax, visualization

I create the following list (When I select one of these options, a Table and Graphics change):

[image]

But it was sorted alphabetically, and I want to sort it by the number of orden I have in my table:

[image]

in order words, I want that my first element will be Sistema, not Acceso Crediticio, and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the list actually? Is that a Filter?

Comment: Yes, its a Filter: When I select one of these options, a Tabla and Graphics change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in Power BI that you can sort a Column using another column. That probably going to solve your issue. Here is a table I have as seen in the **Data** window-

[image]

Now, when I add **country** column in a filter and it looks like below where we can see the value ordered alphabetically and in ascending order (default).

[image]

But I want to show the country value ordered by the country_id column. Now I just I need to go to the **Data** tab and order column **country** with **country_id** as shown below-

[image]

Select the column country and apply the sort by option. And here is the output in the filter after that-

[image]